# How to list a directory with numbers so the user can select one in bash?

Tags: macos, bash, ls

Okay so I'm basically trying to let the user decide which drive they would like to use to install software to. I'd like a question posted simular to "which drive would you like to install to?" and then it lists the drives numbered so that the user can easily select one of the drives. Is there a way to number ls results and then let the user select one. I was thinking about using the case command or maybe an echo and a read, But I just can't get this to work quite right. Also I should add this is in bash on a mac. Thank you so much.

Comment: Normally, you would ask the user to specify this via commandline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `select`:

```
PS3='which drive would you like to install to? '
select dir in */ quit
do
    if [[ $dir == quit ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    echo "$dir"    # or do other stuff
done
```

You can use a `case` statement inside the `select` block if that suits your needs.

Also, see [`dialog`](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/) and [`whiptail`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/whiptail). Unfortunately, neither seem to come with OS X.

Comment: Okay, So in implementation it seems thats its creating a loop. Every time the next bit of my code executes it then reverts back to the question "which drive would you like to install to?". Is this from the "ps3=" or what could cause this, and as long as I use the select command do I need to use the ps3 or can I use a simple echo? Oh also thank you so much!

Comment: @BrandonOney: `PS3` simply sets the prompt for the `select` statement. It's the `select` statement which loops. The `break` statement is what exits the loop - it can be part of an `if` or a `case`. As you can see, I made the directories part of the options to select from, but I added "quit" and a test for it as another option. `EOF` also exits (e.g. the user presses Ctrl-D).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ls | cat -n; read a; ls | head -n $a | tail -n 1
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I'm not positive of how it works, and what is the output variable? Thanks

Comment: `ls | cat -n; read a; d=\`ls | head -n $a | tail -n 1\`; cd $d`